# Problema con header dinámico de JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, headers

hoy me he propuesto hacer un proyecto web con JS, CSS y HTML, y a la hora de incluir el script para tener un header dinámico dentro de mi propia página web, habiendo visto algunos tutoriales, no doy con la forma de poder tener este tipo de header, no funciona. Soy algo principiante con JS y me gustaría recibir consejos y, obviamente, una solución a este problema.

Aquí voy  a dejar el HTML (no es mucho, ya que la he empezado hoy)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>


<html>
    
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="js/script.js" type="text/javascript">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
    
    
    
</head>




<body>
    
    
    <section class="general">
    <section class="section1">
    
        <div class="Text1" style="z-index: 3; font-family: montserrat;">
        
        2021
        
        </div>
        

            
            

                
                    <p class="p1"><a href="2021.html" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">Home</a></p>
                    <p class="p2"><a>Why?</a></p>
                    <p class="p3"><a>Our Team</a></p>
                    <p class="p4"><a>Objectives</a></p>
                
    </section>
    
    
    
    <section class="section2">
    
        <div>
        
        Let's make this year <br>
            <p id="THEBEST">THE BEST!</p>
        </div>
        
    </section>
    
    <section class="section3"> <!-- Imágen de fondo, con flitro. -->
    
        <div>
        
        <img class="image1" src="silhouette-sea-man-freedom-sunset-horizon-4k_1541114229.jpg" alt="QQ">
        
        </div>
        
    </section>
            
    
    
    
    
    <section class="Why-this-page?"></section>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
</section>  
</body>

<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Aquí esta todo mi código de CSS, por si es necesario.

```
body{
    
    background-color: black;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.section1{
    
    
    
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: -5px;
    z-index: 3;
    
    
}
.Text1{
    font-family: Ailerons;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    
}

.Text1Desc{
    
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: montserrat;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    color: white;
    top: 0px;
}



.section2{
    
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    font-size: 90px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 420px;
    z-index: 1;
    
}


#THEBEST{
    
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 120px;
}




.image1{
    
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: .80;
    
}


.section3{
    
    
    
    z-index: 2;
}


.p1{
    
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 75px;
    top: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
    
    
    
    
}

.p2{
    
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 600px;
    top: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
    
    
    
}

.p3{
    
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 400px;
    top: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
    
    
    
}

.p4{
    
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    top: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
    
    
    
}
```

Y aquí estaría el error de JavaScript, lo que no hace el header dinámico.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ){
        $('body').addClass('section1');
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('section1');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Veo que intentas usar jQuery pero no veo el import de jQuery. Estás seguro de que lo has añadido correctamente?

Comment: Lo tengo importado ya, pero sigo sin ver que el header sea dinámico

Comment: Yo lo único que puedo ver es `<link href="js/script.js" type="text/javascript">`, puesto dos veces, una al principio y otra al final. Como entenderás, no podemos saber qué es `script.js` pero sea lo que sea, lo estás añadiendo dos veces por algún motivo? Te recomiendo usar nombres de archivos/variables que indiquen qué es eso, puesto que si no a la larga te complicarás tú mismo la vida, y además es imposible que nadie pueda ayudarte si no pueden saber qué hace/contiene tu código! Te recomiendo hacer un [mre] usando los code snippet que tenemos en SO

Comment: Realmente ha sido un fallo mío el hecho de ponerle dos veces el link, pero, sigo sin entender donde reside el problema, y ya he pasado que el archivo script.js es el que he puesto al final, donde yo creo que reside el problema, aunque tambien puede ser problema de css o html, lo se, por eso vine, necesito un poco de ayuda en cuanto a este tema, mi pregunta hacia ti es si podrias decirme como podría hacer un header dinámico con ese ejemplo, porque tengo asignado a la clase de html section1 como header y es que me he quedado estancado con este problema.

Comment: Te estoy intentando ayudar, pero no me quieres dejar ayudarte. El código que has puesto es correcto, no le pasa nada, así que el error está en la manera en que has añadido la librería de jQuery a tu web. Te repito, no veo por ningún lado el script de jQuery añadido, estás seguro de que lo tienes bien?? Porque tu código javascript lo puedes ver funcionando [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/4be9vs25/) y verás que está funcionando perfectamente.

Comment: Ya está editado correctamente, por cierto, ya da igual, muchas gracias por todo, pero, una ultima cosa, he estado haciendo zoom con chrome y la página en vez de quedarse en medio en el zoom, se queda en la parte izquierda, como lo puedo soluicionar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119132/discussion-between-sershrx-and-benito-b).